# Changing the C parameter of an SVM in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to optimize my SVM, using cross-validation to estimate my performance.

It seems that changing the C parameter does nothing - how come?

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import svm
for C in [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0]:
    clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C)
    scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=6, n_jobs = -1)
    print C, scores
```

The result is

```
> 0.1 [ 0.88188976  0.85826772  0.90118577  0.90909091  0.8972332   0.86561265]
> 0.5 [ 0.88188976  0.85826772  0.90118577  0.90909091  0.8972332   0.86561265]
> 1.0 [ 0.88188976  0.85826772  0.90118577  0.90909091  0.8972332   0.86561265]
> 2.0 [ 0.88188976  0.85826772  0.90118577  0.90909091  0.8972332   0.86561265]
> 4.0 [ 0.88188976  0.85826772  0.90118577  0.90909091  0.8972332   0.86561265]
```

Comment: hi! do you have a sample X (and any other necessary) variables? also, do you see the same values if you don't use `for` but rather hard code C every time you run it? (wondering if it's an odd memory issue in each python session...)

Comment: The feature vector is very large (some 4000 long) so it'd be hard to give a sample X. I'll try recreating the problem with a simpler model maybe.

Comment: You should probably use GridSearchCV for what you are trying to do. http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/grid_search.html

Answer (score 3):

These seems as way to small changes in `C` value to see any differences. Try a set of

```
C = [ 10**x for x in xrange(10) ]
```

in order to check whether everything works fine you should print the **model**, not just the results. Your SVC object contains information regarding support vectors - simply print them to see, that changes in `C` really affects the way algorithm trains SVM.

For linear kernel you can print:

```
print clf.coef_
print clf.intercept_
```

for non-linear kernel:

```
print clf.dual_coef_
print clf.support_vectors_
print clf.intercept_
```

Comment: I tried that (for a 'poly' kernel, tried C=1.0 and C=10,000,000.0), all the results and coefficients are identical. It seems C does not affect anything.

Comment: Did you print the coefficients as suggested? C **does** change everything :) but in case of poly kernel it is also related to the choice of **d** (for some values of **d** changes in **C** may truly be minimal).